# Deja Dup metered connection problem

Tags: backup

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

When the time comes to auto-backup for Deja Dup (every night), I am having a notification something like "Backup delayed. It will start when an unmetered connection detected.". And there is no auto-backup if I don't do it manually.

My laptop is connected to my phone's unlimited internet via hotspot (as it does for years). What means "metered" and how can I fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Metered connection means you pay by megabytes or gigabytes you download/upload from the Internet or you have fixed number of GB of mobile data per month. If you have unlimited mobile data connection, then the connection is unmetered.

Comment: @user68186 I have Ubuntu 20.04. The backup target is Google Drive. My laptop is connected to my phone's internet (tethering).

Comment: Please [edit your queation](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1335792/edit) and put all the new information such as Ubuntu version, the kind of mobile data plan you have, etc.

Comment: This sounds like a deja-dup bug, something similar to the [bug in 2012 and was fixed in 2017](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/deja-dup/+bug/982316). But it is not the same bug. You may want to [file a bug report](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: It looks like deja-dup added this feature in version 35.3, see [here and scroll down](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/deja-dup/-/blob/main/NEWS.md). I have no idea how it determines a "metered connection" and whether it uses the Wifi settings in the answer below or not.

Comment: I think I will create a new issue on the link you gave and ask about the situation to the developer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Look in your network settings, click the cog icon for your connection and at the bottom should be a checkbox for `Metered connection`

[image]

Comment: That checkbox is not clicked. So it means I have an unmetered connection. What is the problem then? Why did Backup software say that I have metered connection? My internet connection is unlimited 4G btw.